# Cluster Marker in android without user location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker, markerclusterer

I am new to clustering marker in android. I implemented ClusterItem and added all other marker[Hotels] and user maker in ClusterManager. But problem is that when i don't add user marker to ClusterManager it does not cluster other maker too.

What i want is all other marker should be clustered expect user maker. Please help me how can i achieve this.

This is how i am creating clustermanager

```
clusterManager = new ClusterManager<ClusterItem>(this, mMap);
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
```

and i am adding clusterItem just like we do

```
    clusterManager.addItem(new ClusterItem(hotelsLocation));
```

Answer (score 0):

*But problem is that when i don't add user marker to ClusterManager it does not cluster other maker too.*

Can you make it more clear ? If you want add or remove a cluster item on the fly, use

```
mClusterManager.addItem(item);
// mClusterManager.removeItem(item);
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

the cluster() method here means, just an item added/removed please calculate clusters again.

Comment: Even if i remove clusterItem of user, blue dot kind of thing represent my location[ which is coming by default]. And cluster does not show any effect

Comment: oh the blue dot,  do you have an intent to make it be part of cluster ?

Comment: no i dont have any intent to use it.. I removed that blue dot . But still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Init the clusterManager like this:

```
clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getActivity(), googleMap);
clusterManager.setRenderer(new OurClusterRenderer(getActivity(), googleMap, clusterManager));
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager);
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(clusterManager.getMarkerManager());
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager);
```

Then add your own marks (Hotels only) and call .cluster():

```
clusterManager.clearItems();
for (HotelModel hotelModel : hotelModelNearMeList) {
    if (hotelModel.getPosition() != null) {
        clusterManager.addItem(hotelModel);
    }
}
clusterManager.cluster();
```

Finally, if you want to add a User Marker:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 1);
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_mylocation));
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

If you follow this steps, your clustering will be done even if you don't add any UserMarker. Hope it helps.